# Loop generates a lot of lines?

Tags: c#, linq

I cannot wrap my head around why this code generates a lot of null-lines:

```
int nr = 0;
foreach (var item in lists.Select(x => x.match_id))
{
    foreach (var match in lists)
    {
        Console.Write(match.nickname
            .Where(x => lists[nr].match_id == match.match_id)
            .Select(z => match.nickname)
            .FirstOrDefault());
    }

    nr++;
}
```

`lists` is an array of objects. The output:
 [image: http://extradelar.se/printscrn.jpg]

Below all of the nulls are the next records, and then more nulls etc. Why?

Comment: Have you verified that all the records have a `nickname`?

Comment: Because you don't filter your nicknames, rather select elements based on the match-id

Comment: Yes, there are 10 nicknames in each object-array

Comment: If you are so sure, why don't you use `First` method instead of `FirstOrDefault`? Just saying.

Comment: Well, your last linq method is `FirstOrDefault()`, which is designed to return `null` if the `Select` method returns no records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To not output the `null`, you need to not call `Console.Write` if the value is `null`.

Try something like this:

```
int nr = 0;
foreach (var item in lists.Select(x => x.match_id))
{
    foreach (var match in lists)
    {
        var n = match.nickname
            .Where(x => lists[nr].match_id == match.match_id)
            .Select(z => match.nickname)
            .FirstOrDefault();

        if (n != null)
        {
            Console.Write(n);
        }
    }

    nr++;
}
```

Comment: While this solves his question... It's really bad programming. He says he has an array of objects. We know that these objects have an Id and a nickname. Now you first loop through the whole list to get the var item (which is I guess an integer). We dont actually do anything with it ???. Then we loop again through the same list as we previously did. In that loop we have match, which is an Object as OP states. Then we want to output the nickname of that object where in the list match_Id equals the match.match_id.

I guess its just a gamble since we dont know what he wants to accomplish...

Comment: Why not add a where clause hinging on the nickname being not null in LINQ query with something like `x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.nickname)` <- I know that is off syntax-wise

Answer (score 0):

You are looping twice through the same Array. I think you want to do:

```
for(int i = 0; i < lists.length; i++){
    Console.Write(item.nickname
        .Where(x=> lists[i].match_id === item.match_id)
        .Select( z=> item.nickname)
        .FirstOrDefault());
}
```

My 2 cents after a quick look..